# Implement `fold` on a "Rose Tree"

Tags: haskell, tree

Given the following algebraic data type, a [Rose Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_tree):

```
data Tree a = Node {
    rootLabel :: a,
    subForest :: [Tree a]
}
```

I attempted a `foldTree` function to fold over this list: (credit to this [class's homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/08-IO.pdf) from 2013:

```
treeFold :: (b -> [b] -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f g tree = f (g (rootLabel tree)) (map (g . rootLabel) (subForest tree))
```

**test**

```
*Party> let tree = Node { rootLabel = 100, subForest = [] }
*Party> let tree2 = Node { rootLabel = 200, subForest = [tree] }
*Party> add tree2
300
```

Please review this implementation.

Given my definition of `treeFold`, I don't see how I could fold over a `Tree Char`, producing a `[Char]/String` result.

My understanding is that, for the return type, `b`, it can't be `[a]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation isn't correct, because it doesn't traverse sub-trees. Consider

```
Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 []]]
```

Then your folding function will only fold over 1 and 2, but not over 3.

If you have a recursive structure like this, a folding function over it must also be recursive. Otherwise it won't be able to traverse arbitrarily large recursive structure.

For the other question: If you specialize the folding function as

```
treeFold :: ([Char] -> [[Char]] -> [Char]) -> (Char -> [Char])
         -> Tree Char -> [Char]
```

by setting `b = [Char]`, you get what you're looking for - converting a `Tree Char` to `String`. You just need to supply the two function for folding, for example

```
treeFold (\x ys -> x ++ concat ys) (: [])
```

---

**Update:** The signature also isn't correct. The general rule is that the folding function should have one additional argument for each constructor of the data type where recursive types (here `Tree a`) are replaced by the result of the fold:

```
treeFold :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
```

For example for a list you have 2 constructors: `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` and `[] :: [a]`, so its folding function is

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Comment: Thank you, Petr. Does my function signature look right?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Updated.

Comment: Why isn't the correct signature's first argument: (a -> [b] -> b)?

Comment: @KevinMeredith You're absolutely right, I mixed up `a` and `b`. Of course, it must be the type of the result. Fixed.