# Implementing `concat` using `foldTree` on Rose Tree

Tags: haskell

I attempted (incorrectly) to implement `foldTree` [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69691/implement-fold-on-a-rose-tree).

Recently, I updated it per [Petr](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/15600/petr-pudl%c3%a1k)'s help:

```
treeFold :: (b -> [b] -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f g tree = f (g (rootLabel tree)) (map (treeFold f g) (subForest tree))
```

I implemented `toList`:

```
toList :: Tree a -> [a]
toList = treeFold (\x y -> x ++ (foldr (++) [] y)) (\x -> [x])
```

**Test**

```
ghci> stringTree
Node {rootLabel = "foo", 
      subForest = 
                [Node {rootLabel = "bar", subForest = []},
                 Node {rootLabel = "bippy", subForest = []},
                 Node {rootLForest = []}]}

ghci> toList stringTree
["foo","bar","bippy","baz"]
```

I'm not sure if it's idiomatic to include the `foldr` call. Nor am I sure if I like the usage of `++`.

Please review this code.

Answer (score 2):

*edit:* indeed, `(++)` will cause perfomance degradation on degenerate left-leaning trees. This is overcome with

```
-- toList = treeFold (\x y -> x ++ (foldr (++) [] y)) (\x -> [x])

toList t = treeFold (\x y -> x . foldr (.) id y) (\x ->([x]++)) t []
```

but that's equivalent to using the `DL` monoid mentioned in Petr Pudlák's answer.

---

Because `foldr (++) [] y` is just `concat y`, you can write it down as `\x y -> concat (x:y)`, or, pointfree,

```
-- treeFold :: (t -> [b] -> b) -> (a -> t) -> Tree a -> b

toList = treeFold ((concat .) . (:)) (: [])
```

but that's minor. Do take note that `treeFold`'s inferred type is more general than what you specified.

Similarly, to sum the tree of numbers,

```
sumRoseTree = treeFold ((sum .) . (:)) id
```

(or replace `id` with some other number-producing function, in cased the tree carries some other type).

Answer (score 2):

You could also generalize `toList` to general [monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). That is, use `mconcat` to concatenate several values and `mappend` (or its synonym `<>`). This will give you the implementation of [`foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap) in `Foldable`:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

-- ...

instance Foldable Tree where
    -- foldMap :: (Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> Tree a -> m
    foldMap f = treeFold (\x xs -> x <> mconcat xs) f
```

or simplified using [η-reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion)

```
    foldMap = treeFold (\x xs -> x <> mconcat xs)
```

Then `toList` comes for free [from Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList) defined as `foldMap (: [])`.

This allows you to use other monoids for which `mappend` is less costly compared to `++` of lists, for example [`Seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html) or [`DList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.7.1.1/docs/Data-DList.html).

Comment: a side note: `(\x xs -> x <> mconcat xs) === (\x xs -> mconcat (x:xs)) === ((mconcat .) . (:))`.